# What does "this._events || (this._events = {});" mean?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have started learning Backbone.js. Currently my JavaScript skills are not too good. I have started to examine the `backbone.js` file and have come across a strange line of code whose purpose I can not figure out. Code sample (if you need more context, manually download [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js) for developers and see line 80):

```
var Events = Backbone.Events = {

  // Bind an event to a `callback` function. Passing `"all"` will bind
  // the callback to all events fired.
  on: function(name, callback, context) {
    if (!eventsApi(this, 'on', name, [callback, context]) || !callback) return this;
    this._events || (this._events = {});
    var events = this._events[name] || (this._events[name] = []);
    events.push({callback: callback, context: context, ctx: context || this});
    return this;
  },
```

What does the line `this._events || (this._events = {});` mean? For me, `_events` looks like an inner variable, but is `(this._events = {})` used for assignment or is it an **or** comparison? Or is `||` a completely different operation in this context?

Comment: As a side note, if you've ever done any PHP, it's similar to doing `$x = !isset($x) ? array() : $x;` ... I think that the JavaScript falsey evaluation syntax is pretty nice, personally. However, there are caveats regarding what's classed as true and false in JS. Reading: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a trick that uses javascripts "falsy" evaluation. It is the same as:

```
if (this._events) {
    // do nothing, this._events is already defined
} else {
    this._events = {};
}
```

The same goes for the line `var events = this._events[name] || (this._events[name] = []);` which could be translated to

```
var events;
if (this._events[name]) {
    events = this._events[name];
} else {
    this._events[name] = [];
    events = this._events[name];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What line “this._events || (this._events = {});” means?

The [**logical OR**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators) (||) executes the first expression `this._events` and if falsy executes the second expression `(this._events = {})`.

In essence it checks if `this._events` is falsy and if so then assigns a new empty object to it.

That way no matter what `this._events` will always be at least an empty object and the code following will be able to execute without issues.

Answer (score 1):

It's a way to write

```
if (!this._events) {
    this._events = {};
}
```

In my opinion it's bad practice to use that kind of short hand, and I think the following line

```
var events = this._events[name] || (this._events[name] = []);
```

is even worse.
Mixing assignment, of the `events` with the creation of `this._events[name]` is quite short, but it's also hard to read. If you don't know what you're doing you might introduce subtle errors that way. That doesn't outweigh the benefits of having it all in one line.

And in the end it will be minified anyway. Let the minifiers take care of stuffing everything in one line. No need to do it yourself.

Comment: You should not consider it just as bad practice. This construct or `this._events = this._events || {};` are not only used to just have a one liner. It is used to make it easier to determine between initializing with a default or checking for a condition. And if you know those patterns and if they are used correctly and consistent it makes it easier to read the code as the [expanded version](http://pastebin.com/STnGEKZr). I don't want to say that this pice of code is perfect. Those patterns for sure should be introduced in the coding guidelines along with the naming convention.

Comment: I see where you're coming from. I also use the defaults pattern using `||` sometimes, but I don't like having side-effects in a boolean logic statement. Also, the `||` pattern breaks down if you allow `0` as a value that doesn't need a default set. In the end, this pattern has mostly caused me more problems that it solved because of those kind of problems (collection initialized with limit 0, but fetching with default of 20). I usually try to make use of `_.defaults` instead.

Comment: Yes I'm award of that problem, and I fully agreed that you have to take care about this. But then the answer (with that comment) is little bit misleading as it - in my opinion - implies that writing the `if (!this._events) { .. }` as the given short hand could introduce those problems, but both the `!this._events` and the `this._events || ...` suffer of the same problem. Don't get more wrong, I fully agree that using such patterns just to make code smaller without using it for  special meaning is bad practice, but I still would not say that using it is bad practice in general.