# Javascript or D3js Notation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How is there an assignment operator in the OR function.

What would be the result of each of the two return statements.

Refer: http://www.d3noob.org/2014/01/tree-diagrams-in-d3js_11.html

```
var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
.data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

nodeEnter.append("text")
.attr("x", function(d) { 
return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13; })
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "this.\_events || (this.\_events = {});" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212926/what-does-this-events-this-events-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your example, usually it is the way used to define unique index in d3

```
var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
.data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });
//here if d.id exists and is truthy, just return d.id; if not, then assign d.id to ++i
```

second is same:

```
if d.children is (defined and truthy value) then return -13
if d.children is not defined or is falsy then return 13
```

(For reference: ["Truthy" and "Falsy" Values](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/))

Comment: Truthy and Falsy.Hmm.. may it is time to learn javascript before D3 .. Thanks huan ..